# How to use key binding with JFrame in java

Tags: java, multithreading, jframe, key-bindings

I am trying to use key binding to control a game (up, down, left, right arrows).  My plan is to use key binding with multi threading, calling some sort of an update method.

My code for the graphics window so far:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Container;

public class Main extends JPanel{
    public Main(){
        JFrame window = new JFrame("New window");
        window.setSize(300, 300);
        window.setVisible(true);
        Container c = window.getContentPane();
        c.add(new Main());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //some code
        //multi threading code
    }
}
```

I have read the documentation for key binding, but I am not sure how to use it for a JFrame.  I think I should add it to c, but I am then not sure how to use the key binding.  Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Key Binding in what way?

Comment: @SamOrozco As in associating a key with an action.  The documentation is  here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use KeyBindings with a component that extends from JComponent, such as a JPanel as the object has to have the `getActionMap()` and `getInputMap()` to allow bindings to be made. JFrame does not extend from JComponent, and so you cannot directly bind to the JFrame, but can bind to any of its components that do satisfy this rule.

So, in your code above, you could add Key Bindings to the Main JPanel or to the JFrame's contentPane, which is a JPanel but will have to be cast as one first.

Your code above though has a problem in that the `c.add(new Main());` in the Main's constructor will cause infinite recursion and thus a StackOverflowException. Either add `this` or put the JFrame creational code within the main method.

Comment: Thank you for seeing this error.  This code is just an example that I wrote fairly quickly.  Are you saying that I can add the key bindings to window, or am I not understanding your explanation properly?

Comment: @SAT: Again, as simple as possible: you can only add Key Bindings to an object that inherits from JComponent. Full stop. If you wonder whether you can add it to some class, check its API and see if it inherits from JComponent. JFrames don't, JPanels do.

Comment: I see now.  Thank you.  I can create a JPanel object using window.getContentPane().

Comment: Yes you can, but you will need to cast the contentPane to JPanel or JComponent do this.

Comment: Okay, so JPanel content = (JPanel) window.getContentPane(); , right?